# Asymptotic expansion of $\zeta(s)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, riemann-zeta, infinite-product

It is well known that
$$
\zeta(s) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s} = \prod_{p \text{ prime}} \frac{1}{1 - p^{-s}}, \quad \Re[s] > 1, \tag{1}$$
but, if $p \leq N$ denotes the primes less than or equal to $N$, can $(1)$ be used to deduce that
$$\sum_{n = 1}^N \frac{1}{n^s} \sim \tilde K \cdot \prod_{p \leq N} \frac{1}{1 - p^{-s}} \quad \text{as} \quad N \to \infty$$
and, in particular,
$$\sum_{n = 1}^N\frac{1}{n} \sim K \cdot \prod_{p \leq N} \frac{1}{1 - 1/p} \quad \text{as} \quad N \to \infty, \tag{2}$$
for some constants $\tilde K, K > 0$? Here, $\sim$ denotes asymptotic equality. There is a sharp estimate for $K$, namely $K = e^{-\gamma}$, where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant (I believe it is one of Mertens' theorems). In any case, does $(2)$ follow from $(1)$?

**Edit**: Note that I am not looking for a proof of Mertens' theorem. I just wish to show that $K > 0$ exists and $K \ne 1$.

Comment: Do you mean $p$ to be prime in $(2)$?

Comment: @anorton Yes. I edited my question.

Comment: If $\Re(s) > 1$ then you can just take $K = 1$, and if $s = 1$ then $K = e^{-\gamma}$ by one of Mertens' theorems, so are you interested in the case when $0 < \Re(s) < 1$ or...?

Comment: @AntonioVargas I apologize for the confusion. I am actually interested in the case when $s \to 1$. It was a typo. By the way, why can we put $K = 1$ if $\Re[s] > 1$?

Comment: Oh, I thought you were interested in the case when $N \to \infty$.  And you can put $K=1$ in that case since, for $\Re(s) > 1$, $$\lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n^s} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^s} = \prod_{p} (1-p^{-s})^{-1} = \lim_{N \to \infty} \prod_{p \leq N} (1-p^{-s})^{-1},$$ so $$\lim_{N \to \infty} \left(\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n^s}\right)\left/\left(\prod_{p \leq N} (1-p^{-s})^{-1}\right)\right. = 1.$$ That is, $$\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n^s} \sim \prod_{p \leq N} (1-p^{-s})^{-1} \qquad \text{as } N \to \infty.$$

Comment: @AntonioVargas Thanks. However, I am particularly interested in the case when $s \to 1$. Note that I am not looking for a full-blown proof of Mertens' theorem. I simply want to know whether $(2)$ follows directly from $(1)$ and why we cannot set $K = 1$.

Comment: If you are interested in what happens when $s \to 1$, why do you have $N \to \infty$ in your post?  Are you asking about how the function $$f(s) = \lim_{N \to \infty} \left(\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n^s}\right)\left/\left(\prod_{p \leq N} (1-p^{-s})^{-1}\right)\right.$$ behaves as $s \to 1$?  Or maybe something else?

Comment: @AntonioVargas Recall that, in general, $f(x) \sim g(x)$ as $x \to x_0$ whenever $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x)/g(x) = 1$ ("$f$ and $g$ are asymptotically equivalent as $x \to x_0$"). In this case $x_0 = N = \infty$. I just wanted to be specific. To avoid ambiguity I wrote $N \to \infty$.

Comment: I'm aware what $\sim$ means, but you wrote "$\ldots \sim \ldots$ as $N \to \infty$" in your post, and you keep mentioning "as $s \to 1$" in the comments.  I still do not know exactly what your question is.  **What** are you seeking the behavior of as $s \to 1$?

Comment: @AntonioVargas Read my post carefully. The question is: Does $(2)$ follow from $(1)$? In other words, can we use $(1)$ to infer that $\sum_{n = 1}^N n^{-1}$ is asymptotically equal to $K \prod_{p \leq N} (1 - 1/p)^{-1}$, where $K > 1$ is some constant?

Comment: Right, I'm just trying to figure out what *that* question has to do with your repeated mentioning of "$s \to 1$" here in the comments.  Anyway, the post has been edited to address my first comment, so I'm happy with that.

Comment: @AntonioVargas Sorry. There was a typo, which I fixed. Initially, I wrote $(2)$ as $\sum_{n = 1}^N n^{-s} \sim K\prod_{p \leq N} (1 - 1/p^s)^{-1}$, so I thought that in your comments you were referring to the original $(2)$.

Comment: Ohhhh, is that the typo you referred to earlier?  Okay, it all makes sense now.  Cheers :-)

Comment: @AntonioVargas Any thoughts?

Comment: To sum up, the question seems to be to **find a proof of Mertens' third theorem based on the factorization (1) of $\zeta(s)$**. What makes you think this should exist? (As so many times, upvotes for unfathomable reasons. @upvoters: Why is this an interesting question?)

Comment: @Did I am not looking for a proof of Mertens' theorem. I just want to prove that $K$ exists. Thanks for editing the question by the way.

Comment: *What makes you think that* a proof of the existence of $K$ and of the fact that $K\ne1$ (*that is*, a little more than the first part of *Mertens' third theorem*), *based on the factorization (1) of ζ(s). should exist*?

Comment: @Did I do not know. That is why I asked this question.

Comment: Sorry but this does not make any sense. You were told, or you think, that there is a link, otherwise you would not ask for it.